# How to call an api for status messages of other api calls progress

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am trying to make two api calls parallely. When X is getting called, Y should go paralleley and it will call recursively itself until api X resolves.
two Calls fires immediately clicking a button

```
function X () {
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
Service.requestAPI(RequestMethod.GET, API_URL.validateProductStatus)
      .then(response => {
resolve(response)
} 
}
}

function Y () {
Service.requestAPI(RequestMethod.GET, API_URL.validateProductStatus)
      .then(response => {
        if(response){
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.onStatusChange()
          },1000)
}
} 
}

async function buttonCLick() {
const XResponse = await X();
Y();
}
```

The above solution doesnt work as expected. The second call Y is becoming sync call instead of async.
Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's what `await` does, it waits for a async call to complete before resuming.
A lot of code is lacking from your sample to provide a solution specific to your use case. But in general, to do async processing while updating dynamic status, you'll need either callbacks or a stream.

```js
let sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

let doAsyncWork = async onProgress => {
  let n = 100;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    await sleep(Math.random() * 100);
    onProgress(i / n);
  }
  onProgress(1);
};

let updateProgress = progress => {
  document.querySelector('div').textContent = progress < 1 ? 
    `Working, ${progress * 100}%` :
    `Complete!`;
};

doAsyncWork(updateProgress);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the api calls. The problem is when the api call in X tries to resolve it blocks the thread of the Y call.

Comment: @RajdeepChandra Of course, that's what `.then` and `await` do! If you don't want to block, then don't use `.then` and `await`. Use my example instead.

Answer (score 0):

`await` will block the execution until `X` is resolved, one way you can achieve this is by using a global variable that determines whether to call `Y` or not :

```js
let callY = true;

const x = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // some api call
    setTimeout(() => resolve("X is reolved"), 3000);
  });
};

const y = () => {
  if (callY) {
    console.log("waiting for x");
    // some api call
    // once it resolves based on the response doing a recursive call
    setTimeout(() => y(), 1000); // calling the function after 3 seconds
  }
};

async function buttonCLick() {
  x().then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    callY = false;
  });
  
  y();
}

buttonCLick();
```

Comment: your implementation is right but in X i am calling an api which resolves a promise and the returned resolution i am catching it in x(). then() where it is blocking the thread of the other api call. If i put the api call in x in a setTImeout(), the Y api call fires as expected but as soon as X gets fired the Y thread is blocked.